# Segmentation fault in access vector C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, vector, segmentation-fault

I'm writing a simple multi-threading program to add and access member in a vector in a multiple thread:
Thread 1: Use `push_back` to add member to vector
Thread 2: Calling a function Iterate through vector and check if the member is already in the vector then return it, otherwise return `NULL`
Some time I faced the Segmentation fault at the thread 2. Is the vector is thread safety for doing what I mention above. I do not have any code to remove member from the vector, only adding more.

Here is the full code of function iterate the vector:

```
Scope* ScopeList::FindScope(int32_t domain, int32_t channel) {
    Scope* findItem = new Scope(domain, channel);
    Scope* resultItem = NULL;
    for(uint32_t i = 0U; i < m_scope_list.size(); i++) {
        if(m_scope_list.at(i) == NULL) {
            continue;
        }
        if(m_scope_list.at(i)->isEqual(findItem)) {
            resultItem = m_scope_list.at(i);
            break;
        }
    }
    delete findItem;
    findItem = NULL;
    return resultItem;
}
```

Here `m_scope_list` is a vector of `Scope` object, which `isEqual` function  is define as follow:

```
bool Scope::isEqual(Scope* scope) {
    if(scope == NULL||!this->m_domain ||!this->m_channel){
        return false;
    }
    bool result = this->m_domain == scope->GetDomain() && this->m_channel == scope->GetChannel();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: `Scope* findItem = new Scope(domain, channel);` never added, so `if(m_scope_list.at(i)->isEqual(findItem))` should not work. Secondly you delete `findItem` but you expect `resultItem` to be pointing to a deleted memory segment.

Comment: No, the vector is not thread safe. Iterating over it while modifying it on another thread can lead to problems, as you are getting. In second thread you are "only" adding more elements: this can result in relocation of the internal array contained in the vector

Comment: @macroland: the `findItem` is only for compare with the current member of vector in the `for` loop. I forgot to add information that `m_scope_list` is a class that have a `vector` as member variable, but not a `vector` itself.

Comment: "`if(m_scope_list.at(i)->isEqual(findItem))` should not work" We do not have access to `isEqual` so we can't say whether or not this is true. Regardless, I recommend getting rid of the dynamic allocation of of `findItem` with `Scope findItem(domain, channel);` and most probably `isEqual(&findItem)` (but consider `bool isEqual( const Scope &)` instead).

Comment: The most likely cause of the error is simultaneous, unrestricted access to the vector as pointed out by others, but to get a full picture and give you a complete answer, we need to see an [mcve].

Comment: I updated the defination of `isEqual` function, hope this would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to synchronize both threads. Because a vector is not thread-safe. If you modify the vector from one thread and access from another then there is a high chance of getting a segmentation fault. You might want to look into [uniqe_lock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock) or [lock_guard](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) and [mutex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) for details. If you don't understand anything about their usages then leave a comment. Happy Multithreading.

**EDITED:** From comment made by @GianPaolo

`push_back` will modify the internal state of the vector, in a way that can be not thread safe. if you call push_back when the vector as already reached its capacity, the current T[] array in use will be copied in a new T[] (of higher size), and the original will be deleted. Not something you can safely do while another thread is iterating on the vector

Comment: I don't quite understand how can it got segmentation fault, since I don't modify member that already existed in the `vector`, but only add new member to `vector` using `push_back`. How can this not work, Can you explain further?

Comment: Have you seen the comment made by Gian Paolo on your Original Post?

Comment: @ĐăngHảiLiễu, `push_back` will modify the interna state of the vector, in a way that can be not thread safe. if you call push_back when the vector as already reached its capacity, the current T[] array in use will be copied in a new T[] (of higher size), and the original will be deleted. Not something you can safely do while another thread is iterating on the vector

Comment: @GianPaolo Ah ok I understand now. I tried with the mutex lock and problem is solved. Thanks you all for the help :)